# Search results don't show when searching SKUs

Tags: wordpress, search

My website is a **woocommerce** site. My problem is the search box. Every time I search using SKU there is no result. It only shows results when I search the posts, products and pages results. It is not showing woocommerce SKU products.

How can I fix this WordPress search result?

Here is my WordPress **search.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
<div class="container">
    <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
        <div id="left-area" >   
    <?php
     global $wpdb; 
     $s = (isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']) ? urldecode($_GET['s']) : false;

     if($s){    
     $where = ' title  LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape($s) ) . '%\'';

     $arr_title = explode(' ',$s);
     foreach($arr_title as $search_term):   
       $where .= ' OR title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
     endforeach;


     $query = "
     SELECT * 
        FROM ( SELECT p.ID as id, p.post_title as title, p.post_name as slug, p.post_excerpt as excerpt,  'post' AS type  FROM  $wpdb->posts  AS p WHERE p.post_type IN  ('post', 'page', 'product')  AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT t.term_id as id, t.name as title, t.slug as slug, tx.description as excerpt, 'term' AS type  FROM $wpdb->terms AS t LEFT JOIN   $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tx ON  t.term_id = tx.term_id  WHERE tx.taxonomy NOT IN ('product_tag', 'post_tag')
    ) AS tb  WHERE $where ";


   //start pagination
   $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);  
   $total = count($results);
   $paged = (isset($_GET['paged'])) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;   
   $limit = 50;
   //end pagination

   $offset = $paged ? ($paged - 1) * $limit : 0;
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " LIMIT $offset, $limit ");


        if ($results) :
            foreach( $results as $row ) :  
              $url_img = false; $permalink = false;
              if($row->type=='post'){ 
//                  $url_img = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'small');
//                echo 'post_id= ' . $row->ID . ', att_id= ' . (int)$attachment_id . '<br>';
              $result = wp_get_attachment_image_src (get_post_thumbnail_id($row->id), 'medium');
              $url_img = $result['url'];

                $permalink = get_permalink($row->id);
              } 
              if($row->type=='term'){
                 $permalink = get_bloginfo('url').'/products/'.$row->slug;      
              }

            ?>

<article id="post-<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="et_pb_post post-<?php echo $row->id; ?>"> 

<?php if($url_img): ?> 
<a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $url_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->title; ?>" /> </a>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo (!is_wp_error($permalink)) ? $permalink : '#'; ?>"><?php echo $row->title; ?></a></h2>
<?php   echo $row->excerpt; ?>
<div class="read-more-link-container"><a href="<?php echo (!is_wp_error($permalink)) ? $permalink : '#'; ?>" class="read-more-link"> Read More</a></div>
</article>



        <?php endforeach;

        if($total > $limit):      
         $pl_args = array(
         'base'     => add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
         'format'   => '',
         'total'    => ceil($total / $limit),
         'current'  => max(1, $paged),
         );
        echo paginate_links($pl_args); 
        endif;

        else : get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
        endif;
     }else{
         get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
     }
        ?>
        </div> <!-- #left-area -->

        <?php get_sidebar('search'); ?>   
    </div> <!-- #content-area -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You could just put the SKU of your product into the product title. No need to mess around with code then.

Comment: is there another way?

Comment: I mean, yeah, there are plenty of off the shelf plugins (free ones) that will add that functionality without you changing the code(aside from maybe replacing your search box), but I administer a £50m/y turnover site with >8000 products that puts the SKU in the title of the product. It works for them, so why try and re-invent the wheel? It'll benefit your SEO to have the SKU in the title too. Personally if you're looking to rewrite your search function I'd rewrite that entire block and use a WP_Query instead of $wpdb queries, the code would be a lot nicer.

Comment: (sic) it'll benefit your seo IF your SKU is the products MPN